# Find formula produces negative number

Tags: function, find

Background:

I am using census data from 1999 that is in a text file format. There is not a distinct delimiter being used in the file and excel does not import the data correctly. Excel does separate the rows correctly, however, all of the column data is in a single cell.

A sample cell of data is:

```
01 07000 Birmingham city, AL                249,459    265,940     -16,481        -6.2      1        51    67
```

I attempted to use the FIND formula to find the word "city", to test the formula, and the result is a negative number. Specifically, the number is "-21".

I have looked in a few excel references and I have found nothing to explain this.  Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the delimiter is not a tab?

Comment: When I fixed your formatting, it seems like the original is a fixed-width file; there is an option in Excel import for it.